# Widget doesn't change when I use getX in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The state is managed with getX, and the initial state is false.
When the button is pressed, it changes to true, and I tried to express it as a Text widget to indicate the change, but the widget does not change. What's the problem?

text widget keeps showing only 'false'

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(home : Home()));
}

class BoolItem extends GetxController{
  dynamic item=false.obs;
  changeItem()=> item=true;
}


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final BoolItem b=Get.put(BoolItem());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('welcome')),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), 
          onPressed: (){
            b.changeItem();
            }
          ),
          b.item == true 
          ? Text('true')
          : Text('false')
        ]
    ))        
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `FloatingActionButton` with `Obx`

```dart
Obx(
()=> FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), 
      onPressed: (){
        b.changeItem();
       }
      ),
      b.item == true 
        ? Text('true')
        : Text('false')
)
```

Also update  `changeItem()=> item=true;` to  `changeItem()=> item.value=true;`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `final BoolItem b = Get.put(BoolItem());` from the `build` method in your widget. Every time the build method is called, a new `BoolItem` is created with a value of `false` which results in it never changing to true.